# How can I determine which condition on WHERE clause fails?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// cookies
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| id | user_id |       token       |   expire   |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| 1  | 32423   | dki3j4rf9u3e40... | 1467586386 |
| 2  | 65734   | erhj5473fv34gv... | 1467586521 |
| 3  | 21432   | 8u34ijf34t43gf... | 1467586640 |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I have this query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM cookies
WHERE user_id = :id AND
      token   = :token
```

**Note:** Always the result is either *one* row or *zero* row. *(token column is `unique`)*

When there is a matched row, ok, all fine, but when there isn't any matched row, I want to understand why?

- `user_id` exists but `token` doesn't
- `token` exists but `user_id` doesn't
- non of those columns doesn't exist

How can I determine the reason of *"no row selected (matched)"* ?

---

**EDIT:** Here is all possible outputs:

1. row exists
2. row doesn't exist because `user_id = :id` is *false*
3. row doesn't exist because `token = :token` is *false*
4. row doesn't exist because both `user_id = :id` and `token = :token` are *false*
5. row doesn't exist because `user_id = :id` and `token = :token` are *true* but not in the same row.

Comment: Search about `case when`.

Comment: So the query succeeds if and only if both conditions hold, fails otherwise. if there's no pair id-token that matches input pair it will fail.

Comment: Do you want multiple result columns?

Comment: Rows. In the table where at least one condition - the id in this case, is strictly unique it's practically impossible, as it will violate the key condition.

Comment: @Amit No .. I just want to know one row exists or not. if not, why? 1. `user_id = :id` is *false*?  2. `token = :token` is *false*? 3. both of them are *false*? Well, I want to know which one it is, 1? 2? 3?

Comment: So the row will never exist unless both id and token provided will match one of the rows.

Comment: That's not clear at all. Exemplify exactly what's the output you want to have in each scenario (your current query either returns a single row with the value "1" or no rows at all - what do you want to have instead?)

Comment: You can't find this out from just the one query you have. Your database will simply determine that there are no rows that match the query—it won't care which part of the query is the one that makes this so. You'll have to run separate queries to find out if the token or the user ID is empty.

Comment: Much better now, but not quite done... what it both exist, but not in the same row?

Comment: @Amit Do you mean both `user_id = :id` and `token = :token` are true but not in the same row?

Comment: Yes... that's what I wrote (except for the auto-correct mistake.. :-)

Comment: @Amit Actually what you asked was a great question `:-)` .. That should be one more case. I Edited the question.

Comment: It seems to be too much logic for a simple query. You can either encode the information differently, or use a stored procedure to make that readable and maintainable

Comment: Edit: everyone is being sily. You need to know what the cardinality of your columns are and whether there are NULL values in your list. Also, The WHERE clause will ignore NULL since SQL cannot assume the value. I would give a more detailed answer, but after 9pm PST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This always returns one row. 1 for matched if there is a match otherwise 0. It also shows if the userID or the token exists in the cookies table. Using this method you can determine why the where clause failed.

```
SELECT (  select count(*) > 0 matched from cookies where user_id = :id  and token   = :token ) matched
, ( select count(*) > 0 userIdExists from cookies where user_id = :id ) userIdExists
, ( select count(*) > 0 tokenExists from cookies where token = :token ) tokenExists
```

Comment: You don't need `FROM cookies` since you're not selecting anything from it, but it will cause an empty result set (no rows) if the table is empty.

Comment: Good point @Amit on the 'FROM cookies'. The empty result set is an edge case. Edited the answer.

Comment: Very ingenious solution. +1! You don’t really need to name the selected columns in the subqueries, though, do you? As long as you name the columns in the main query, shouldn’t it give precisely the same result?

Comment: Naming in the subqueries is not required but I tend to always name things explicitly. It helps when you're reading your code 5 years later on.

Comment: I probably got the idea some time after reading 'Thinking in sets' by Joe Celko. It's a great book for insights in how to work with SQL databases. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=joe+celko%27s+thinking+in+sets&oq=joe+celko%27s+thinking+in+sets&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.799j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

**PREFACE:** This problem, *notwithstanding my dislike of MySQL*, was a rather tough puzzle to solve. No use of an FULL OUTER JOIN made it even harder. Even the "solution" I initially gave was insufficient for the task.

OUTER JOINS behave in a specific pattern, and it was important to think about each inner query as independent from the outer opposite side as the explicit direction.

```
SELECT A.Col_A, B.Col_B
TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

This query only produces results if TableA has something to match TableB with. Because every nested query is logically **the same** as the above, even adding a dummy table only left me with just the result from the dummy table and me feeling like a...*dummy*.

While some smart users have tried UNION/UNION ALL to solve this, that answer is unreliable and actually failed when I attempted to use the same table twice.

- **The Solution: FOR REAL!!**

The trick is to guarantee the results will always return.

```
SELECT C.user_id
     , B.token
FROM (SELECT NULL AS C) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT token
                 FROM  Example
                 WHERE token = @token) AS B ON 1 = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_id
                 FROM Example
                 WHERE user_id = @user_id) AS C ON 1 = 1
```

- We use a DUMMY table to ensure we always get a row...even if it is empty.
- Notice `On 1 = 1`. That guarantees that the results from both sides will return and since we made sure those tables only retrieved the exact information we wanted, bingo! we get out beautiful solution that will work regardless of whether one or both sides are `NULL`.

**A RECHECK ON THE ORIGINAL PROCEDURE**

**TABLE DECLARATIONS**:

```
CREATE TABLE sys.EXAMPLE (ID INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
                    , user_id INT NULL
                    , token NVARCHAR(100) NULL
                    , `expire` INT NULL ); 
INSERT INTO sys.EXAMPLE (user_Id, token, `expire`)
VALUES  (32423, N'dki3j4rf9u3e40...', 1467586386)
      , (65734, N'erhj5473fv34gv...', 1467586521)
      , (21432, N'8u34ijf34t43gf...', 1467586640);
```

*-- My `MySQL Workbench` bugs out at the beginning, for some reason the variables are persisting beyond the transaction.*

**PROCEDURE SOLUTION**

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE sys.MyExample
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sys.MyExample(IN user_ID INT, IN token NVARCHAR(255) )   
BEGIN

SELECT B.token, C.user_id INTO @token_chk, @user_chk
FROM (SELECT NULL AS C) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT token
                FROM  sys.Example
                WHERE token = @token
                 LIMIT 1) AS B ON 1 = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_id
                 FROM sys.Example
                 WHERE user_id = @user_id
                 LIMIT 1) AS C ON 1 = 1;

IF @user_chk IS NOT NULL AND @token_chk IS NOT NULL
-- RESULT_1: FOUND BOTH COLUMNS
THEN SELECT 'FOUND IT';
    ELSE IF @user_chk IS NOT NULL AND @token_chk IS NULL
-- RESULT_2: TOKEN IS MISSING
         THEN SELECT 'TOKEN IS MISSING';
         ELSE IF @user_chk IS NULL AND @token_chk IS NOT NULL
-- RESULT_3: USER_ID IS MISSING
                    THEN SELECT 'user_ID IS MISSING';
                    ELSE IF @user_chk IS NULL AND @token_chk IS NULL
-- RESULT_4: BOTH USER_ID AND TOKEN ARE MISSING
                          THEN SELECT 'BOTH user_id AND token are missing';
                          ELSE -- return message saying that an unknown error has occurred
                          SELECT 'AN UNKNOWN ERROR HAS OCCURRED';
                          END IF;
                    END IF;
            END IF;
    end if;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that this works on T-SQL and works in MySQL before I run the PROCEDURE. For some reason, I am having a bug where the second variable in my proc loses its value during the query...even when I explicitly call the same value before the query inside the Procedure.

```
-- Should Return complete set
    CALL sys.MyExample(21432, 'erhj5473fv34gv...');
-- Should Return 'token is missing'
    CALL sys.MyExample(21432, 'erhj5473fv34gv..X'); 
-- Should Return 'user_id is missing'
    CALL sys.MyExample(2143, 'erhj5473fv34gv...'); 
-- Should Return 'Both user_id AND token are missing'
    CALL sys.MyExample(2143, 'erhj5473fv34gv..X');
```

Comment: I seem to have run afoul designing this in T-SQL first..oops, correcting problems

Comment: So you know, I really hate writing in MySQL. The lack of consistency in MySQL is frustrating.

Comment: The hassle you have with the mysql stored procedure is one of the variables has the same name as one of the columns in the tables. I normally put an underscore after the variable name being passed in and I also normally have local variables which I set to the passed in variables. So for example I'd name token as token_, and I'd set @ token to equal token_ and then use @ token in the stored procedure. Using local variables is not necessary but it helps a great deal if you want to use dynamic sql as concatenation with local variables always works.

Comment: This is brilliant. This has been one of the most useful StackOverflow answers for me! I wish I could reward it with more than 10 points. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (that I'm aware of, at least) to get this kind of information from just one query like the one you have here. Your database will simply run the query with the combined criteria you provide and conclude that those criteria either match or don't match any rows. It won't bother itself with exactly which of your criteria made it match or not match any rows.

Assuming you are using these queries as part of some server-side page logic (like a PHP file), I'd say three queries is the minimum you can do this in.

1. The query you already have, which returns a row only if there is a match between the token and the user ID you're looking up.
2. A query to return the number of rows that match the token.
3. A query to return the number of rows that match the user ID.

If query #1 returns a row, the last two are not needed, of course: option #1 is satisfied, skip along to subsequent code. But if it doesn't, you'll need both the other queries to determine which of the other four possible options reflects the state of things:

If query #3 returns more than zero rows and query #2 returns zero rows, the user ID exists but the token doesn't—option #2 satisfied.

If query #2 returns more than zero rows and query #3 returns zero rows, the token exists but the user ID doesn't—option #3 satisfied.

If both queries return zero rows, neither token nor user ID exists—option #4 satisfied.

If both queries return more than zero rows, both token and user ID exist, but since query #1 didn't return any rows, they don't exist in the same row—option #5 satisfied.