# Is it possible to know what UPDATE "WHERE" statement caused not to update without doing a second query?

Tags: mysql, joomla, where-clause

I hava a Joomla DB Query (mysql) that updates something in the DB if all 3 WHERE clauses are met. I want to know if there is way to extract from the update mysql query which "WHERE" statement failed in updating?

I ask this because if COUNT = 1 (which means the DB is already updated and nothing should happen) I want to relay an error like "already updated before" instead of just "not updated".

I of course could do a select query if the update query fails but that means a second query and i was just wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this problem. Maybe a sql function i haven't heard of or something else. So i could do with just one database query.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->update($db->quoteName('#__table'));
    $query->set($db->quoteName('field1') . ' = ' . $db->quote($value1))
          ->set($db->quoteName('field2') . ' = ' . $db->quote($value2));
          if ($value3 !="") {
    $query->set($db->quoteName('field3') . ' = ' . $db->quote($value3));
          }
    $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($rowid))
          ->where($db->quoteName('talentuid') . ' = ' . $db->quote($tid))
          ->where($db->quoteName('count') . ' = ' . $db->quote(0));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->execute();
    // Check for affected rows.
    if ($db->getAffectedRows() > 0) {
        return '{"success": "true"}';
    } else {
        return '{"success": "false"}';
    }
```

Comment: Don't believe so, after all the query didn't fail, there just wasn't data that matched the conditions.

Comment: Ah yeah thats true; But no way to get the results of the conditions? I now added a second select query to fetch the row i wanted to edit and check the count value.

Comment: All I can say is that I don't know of one, there are probably workarounds (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175065/how-can-i-determine-which-condition-on-where-clause-fails) but imo they are hacks that add a large amount of complexity for a small gain.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @TLWeb can you please produce a small db-fiddle.com demo that represents the challenge and explain your desired effect.  As I reread your question, I wonder if I am misunderstanding your goal.

Comment: Please always post all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange because it suffers from receiving too few daily posts.  https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla  Regarding this question, do you want to INSERT a row if the two id values are not matched? @TLW